# What is Python's equivalent to 'ulimit'?

Tags: python, unix, resources, ulimit

I'm trying to implement a check on system resources for the current shell (basically everything in [`ulimit`](https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html)) in Python to see if enough resources can be allocated. I've found the [`resource`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html) module, but it doesn't seem to have all the information `ulimit` provides (e.g. `POSIX message queues` and `real-time priority`). Is there a way to find the soft and hard limits for these in Python without using external libraries? I'd like to avoid running `ulimit` as a subprocess if possible but if it's the only way, will do so.

Comment: The `resource` module is the right place. It just looks like it hasn't been updated to know about resource limits that were added in recent Linux versions. `RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE` was added in 2.6.8, `RLIMIT_RRTIME` in 2.6.12.

Comment: You might be able to look up the values of the constants in the C header files and use them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `resource.getrlimit()`. If there's no constant in the `resource` package, look it up in `/usr/include/bits/resource.h`:

```
$ grep RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE /usr/include/bits/resource.h
  __RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE = 12,
#define RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE __RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE
```

Then you can define the constant yourself:

```
import resource
RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE = 12
print(resource.getrlimit(RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE))
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked out well, just have to make sure to catch `ValueError` in case the resource isn't defined on the OS.

Comment: I found the constants are also defined within the `resource` module i.e. `resource.RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE`