# Python resource module does not support "pipe size" and "virtual memory" resource limits

Tags: python, linux, ulimit

I have a requirement to measure the system resources on the host vm and compare it with the baseline limits.

the [resource](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/resource.html) module provides with most of the values but I am unable to get below 2 limits from [resource](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/resource.html) module in comparison with `ulimit -a`

1. pipe size --> The pipe size in 512-byte blocks
2. virtual memory --> The maximum amount of virtual memory available to the shell and, on some systems, to its children

I did check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56960022/6113778) answer and did a mapping between `ulimit -a` and `/usr/include/bits/resource.h` which I have pasted below. I could not find any equivalent parameters in `/usr/include/bits/resource.h` for the above 2 system resources.

I'd like to avoid running `ulimit` as a subprocess. Is there any alternative in python?

**Mapping between `ulimit -a` and `/usr/include/bits/resource.h`**

[image: Mapping]

Comment: See [the bash ulimit implemention](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/ulimit.def) to see how that shell calculates those values.

Comment: But to summarize, VM size is stack + data sizes, and pipe size is a compile time value (no idea how to access it from python or I'd post an actual answer)